# kdl_parser and catkin

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In catkin workspace I create package:

```
catkin_create_pkg leg_kinematics std_msgs rospy roscpp kdl_parser
```

In `leg_kinematics/src/leg_kinematics.cpp`:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <kdl_parser/kdl_parser.hpp>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    KDL::Tree my_tree;
    ros::NodeHandle node;
    return 0;
}
```

In `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(leg_kinematics)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  kdl_parser
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
)

catkin_package()

include_directories( include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(leg_kinematics src/leg_kinematics.cpp)
target_link_libraries(leg_kinematics ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

After `catkin_make` I got error:

```
CMakeFiles/leg_kinematics.dir/src/leg_kinematics.cpp.o: In function `main':
leg_kinematics.cpp:(.text+0x58): undefined reference to `KDL::Tree::Tree(std::string const&)'
CMakeFiles/leg_kinematics.dir/src/leg_kinematics.cpp.o: In function `KDL::TreeElement::~TreeElement()':
leg_kinematics.cpp:(.text._ZN3KDL11TreeElementD2Ev[_ZN3KDL11TreeElementD5Ev]+0x27): undefined reference to `KDL::Segment::~Segment()'
leg_kinematics.cpp:(.text._ZN3KDL11TreeElementD2Ev[_ZN3KDL11TreeElementD5Ev]+0x38): undefined reference to `KDL::Segment::~Segment()'
```

Why?)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/106351/kdl_parser-and-catkin/) by [tuuzdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/8026/tuuzdu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2013-12-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at `kdl_parser`'s `CMakeLists.txt`, it doesn't export its dependency on `orocos_kdl`, which is where your missing symbol is:

https://github.com/ros/robot_model/blob/hydro-devel/kdl_parser/CMakeLists.txt#L20

On one hand, `kdl_parser` might should export this as a dependency, but on the other hand, you are using `orocos_kdl` symbols directly. Therefore you should probably also directly depend on it in your `package.xml`, `find_package` it in your `CMakeLists.txt`, and include the appropriate header in your c++ file, and not rely on the `#include <kdl_parser/kdl_parser.hpp>` line to bring in the `orocos_kdl` symbols you need.

If you think this is a bug in `kdl_parser`, I would open a ticket against it in the `robot_model` repository:

https://github.com/ros/robot_model/issues

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2